# Break keyword vs Variable in WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, while-loop, break

We are using `WHILE` loop in SQL Server 2008 instead of Cursor. Now I want to find which method is best to write `WHILE` loop in my procedure.

**Method 1 (Using BREAK Keyword):**

```
DECLARE @V_Counter INT = 1;

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT @V_Counter;
    SET @V_Counter = @V_Counter + 1;

    IF @V_Counter = 4
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
END
```

**Method 2 (Using BOOL VARIABLE):**

```
DECLARE @V_Counter INT = 1, @V_CloseLoop TINYINT = 1;

WHILE (@V_CloseLoop = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT @V_Counter;
    SET @V_Counter = @V_Counter + 1;

    IF @V_Counter = 4
    BEGIN
       SET @V_CloseLoop = 0;
    END
END
```

**My questions are:**

- Which method I have to use or both are same?
- Is there any other method which I can use?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *We are using WHILE loop ... instead of cursor* - a `WHILE` is still almost as bad as a cursor. You should check if you can avoid using `WHILE` and go with a truly set-based approach. **THAT** would really make a noticeable difference in speed

Comment: @marc_s Can you provide me any link of that approach or any example. I want to implement best approach instead of cursor. I found that While loop is better than cursor. So I am trying to implement that in my procedure.

Comment: Just search Google (or Bing) for `SQL Server Thinking in Sets` and you'll have **plenty** of links, e.g. [T-SQL Foundations: Thinking in Sets](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-foundations-thinking-sets) and **many, many more!**

Comment: in many cases using inline functions will also help to avoid cursors. It will speed up more.

Comment: @revoua Please be specific. I have to perform set of operations and business loginc on each row of table. How can I implement that.

Comment: via general query you prepare all values for all rows and after you make bulk updates/inserts etc. Of course it depends on real data and your logic. Maybe you really need cursors.

Comment: I am trying to put my whole business login in procedure for that I have to use cursor but I don't want to use is. So alternative of that I am using WHILE loop. I want to know which method is better using break statement or bool variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Which method I have to use or both are same?
>   No, both are not same.

setting the variable to zero will still execute the lines after that, but nothing else in the loop will be executed after the break.

```
DECLARE @V_Counter INT = 1;

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT @V_Counter;
    SET @V_Counter = @V_Counter + 1;

    IF @V_Counter = 4
    BEGIN
       BREAK;
    END
    PRINT 'STACKOVERFLOW' // this is not executed.
END   


DECLARE @V_Counter INT = 1, @V_CloseLoop TINYINT = 1;

WHILE (@V_CloseLoop = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT @V_Counter;
    SET @V_Counter = @V_Counter + 1;

    IF @V_Counter = 4
    BEGIN
       SET @V_CloseLoop = 0;
    END
    PRINT 'STACKOVERFLOW' // this is executed.
END
```

Using break will always be a clean approach, than setting the variable to zero, as the code will be easy to maintain when we use break than the other way around.

Comment: Thank for the answer but I have not written code after the IF condition. I have written whole business logic before IF condition. So which method is better to use?

Comment: None of them. Use set based statements, avoid using cursors and while loops

Comment: Sorry, a `break` is **not** a clean approach. It is generally considered as bad programming style. Use it only if you have a good reason.

Comment: @JesúsLópez  +1 for "use set based statements" !

Answer (score 0):

A `break`is considered as "bad programming style". So better to use a variable. Except if you have a good reason.

But try to avoid `while` loops at all. In SQL Server, you can very often replace loops with good SQL statements which do everything in one rush.

Comment: Thank for the answer but I have not written code after the IF condition. I have written whole business logic before IF condition which includes more than 50 queries as per my business logic. So how can I eliminate the use of  WHILE loop?

Comment: @SaharshShah I can answer this only when I would see your whole business logic. In SQL Server, you have generally a different approach as in Java or C#. Programming in SQL should not done in loops, it is done with statements which handle a lof of things in just **one** statement.  Then you also get best performance. Loops are often very slow and weak. BTW, I don't understand your particular loop here at all - you are just counting a counter up to 4 ...

Comment: It is a sample code. I am running the loop dynamically.

Comment: @SaharshShah What do you mean with dynamically? Are you generating code?

Answer (score 0):

a) What are you doing here at all? I see a counter being counted up to 4 ... ;)

b) You could rewrite it like this:

```
DECLARE @V_Counter INT = 1;

WHILE (@V_Counter < 4)
BEGIN
    PRINT @V_Counter;
    SET @V_Counter = @V_Counter + 1;
END
```